# Combining swipe tabs with sticky header

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on a Twitter client for Android. For the profile view we want to use a header that partially sticks to the top, like in Google Play Newsstand (which is pretty buggy) and the Google+ profile page.

[Illustrated what I'm looking for http://marijnvdwerf.nl/u/201402022218-stickyswipetabs.png](http://marijnvdwerf.nl/u/201402022218-stickyswipetabs.png)

I managed to implement a sticky bar with a simple listview thanks to Roman Nurik's [Scrolling Tricks](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/1Sb549FvpJt) and [this GitHub project](https://github.com/ideaismobile/Android-ScrollViewTricks). Swipeable tabs were easily autogenerated with Studio. The problem is that I'm not able to combine them properly, and everything I do feels like a dirty hack.

Comment: Hi @marijnvdwerf, did you ever get this fixed/working?

Comment: Not yet, but I'll probably take this up again in the upcoming week.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at these posts:

- [Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager](https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager)
- [The old design of the Airbnb app](http://nerds.airbnb.com/host-experience-android/)
- [Making That Google Plus Profile Screen](http://antoine-merle.com/blog/2013/10/04/making-that-google-plus-profile-screen/)